# Cor Spinner ProgressDialog - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Como altero a cor padrão do ProgressDialog (Spinner) no android? Segue abaixo código que estou utilizando:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle("Título);
        progress.setMessage("Mensagem");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvi o problema com o seguinte código:

Adicionei um layout para minha ProgressDialog

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.styleProgressDialog);
```

E personalizei as cores no meu style da seguinte forma:

```
<style name="styleProgressDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:tint">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa alterar a propriedade `progressTint` com a cor que você deseja.

Pode fazer isso diretamente no xml do seu layout ou via código:

```
progress.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

Comment: É que o _setProgressTintList_ seria para o uso do _ProgressBar_, eu estou usando o **ProgressDialog**...

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910028/using-custom-progressdialog-android